# Parametrization of a curve 3

Tags: calculus, parametric

I asked a pretty similar question like this one yesterday but I want to be sure that I'm starting to grasp the concept now so heres another one.

The question goes like this:

a) Parametrize the unit circle centered around origo. Counter-clockwise

b) Parametrize the circle with radius 2 centered around origo. Counter-clockwise

c) Parametrize the unit circle centered around (1,2). Counter-clockwise

d) Parametrize the unit circle centered around origo. Clockwise.

e)Parametrize the ellipse $3x^2 + 4 y^2 = 12 $

f) Change the interval, if you used $ [0, 2 \pi] $ now use $[0,1]$

g) Write an equation for every parametrization

So: My answers are like these:

a) $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

$x=cos(t)$ , $y=sin(t)$

b) $x^2 + y^2 = 2$

$x=\sqrt{2}cos(t)$, $y=\sqrt{2}sin(t)$

c)  $(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 1$

$x=1+cos(t)$ , $y=2+sin(t)$

d) $x = sin(t)$ , $y=cos(t)$ (since it's clockwise)

e) $3(x^2)+4(y^2)=12$ which gives:

$ \frac {x^2} {4} + \frac {y^2} {3} = 1$

$x=2cos(t)$ , $ y = \sqrt 3 sin(t)$

f) I'm pretty clueless here. I only know how to handle parametrization of circles when you know that $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = d^2$ gives $x = a + dcos(t) $ (and the same for Y but with sin). So, I think the problem is that I don't really understand why that formula works, otherwise I assume it would be pretty simple, right? Any tips here?

g) Pretty clueless here to, does it have anything to do with eliminating the parameter?

Sorry for a big post but I feel like it's important that I really grasp these concepts. I hope a-e is correct so it's basically just f and g I need help with anyway. Although, I guess it's tied with a-e as well since I probably don't know what I'm actually doing there...

Comment: for point "g" it seems that you are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is correct.

To parametrize clockwise you can also set $t'=-t \implies \cos t'=\cos t \quad \sin t'=-\sin t$.

For point $f$ just set

$$t=2\pi z \quad z\in[0,1]$$

For point $g$ you are done, eliminating the parameter lead to the cartesian form from which you started.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the answer. I have another question though, which I feel it might be unnecessary to create a new thread for. When parametrizing a function for example $y^2 = x + 1$ can I just say that $y = t $?. 

In this case it would be: $y = t$ , $x=t^2-1$ as the parametric form

Comment: Yes of course, you can choose any expression in t which satisfy the equation, indeed we have infinite parametrization for a single curve.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry, i don't really understand why $cos(t') = cos(t)$ while $sin(t') = - sin(t) $ when $t' = -t$ ?

Comment: Since cos is an even function while sin is odd.

Comment: Oh that's right. By the way, is b) really correct? Wouldn't it be $\frac {(x-1)^2} {2^2} $ which would give $x = 2cos(t)$ ?

Comment: b) is correct since your parametrization satisfy the equation and take all values for the circle

Comment: Hmm, but isn't the formula $ \frac {(x)^2} {2^2} + \frac {y^2} {2^2} $ since the radius is 2 which would make my equation $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ wrong?

Comment: If I read correctly it is $$x^2+y^2=2\cos^2 t+2\sin^2 t=2(\cos^2 t+\sin^2t)=2$$